# Fijar valor a mat select cuando edito en Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Buenos días soy nuevo en Angular y estoy intentando editar un producto; todos los valores los cargo en el formulario pero tengo un problema al intentar cargar el valor de la marca del producto en un mat select. Este es el código de mis clases:

```
export class Producto {

indice:number;
codigo:String;
undmed:String;
stock:number;
descripcion:String;
preciovta:number;
costo:number; 
igv:string;
icbper:string;
marca:Marca; //en el backend es de tipo Marca
isEdit: boolean;
```

}

Clase que implementa la Marca

```
 export class Marca {

    idmarca:number;
    nombre:string;
   // isEdit: boolean;

}
```

Formulario html en el que se ingresan los datos del producto

```
<mat-card-content>
<form  [formGroup]="addEditProductoForm" 
        (ngSubmit)="addEditProductoForm"
        [class.error]="!addEditProductoForm.valid && addEditProductoForm.touched"
class="col s12">

  

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Marca</mat-label>
      <mat-select   formControlName="marca" id="marca" >
      
        <mat-option *ngFor="let mar of marca" [value]="mar">
        {{mar.nombre}}
       </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error >{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
   
    <br />

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Código</mat-label>
      <input matInput  formControlName="codigo" id="codigo"  [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required >
      <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field><br />

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Unidad de medida</mat-label>
      <mat-select  formControlName="undmed" id="undmed" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let und of unidadmedida" [value]="und.nombre">
        {{ und.nombre }}
       </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field><br />

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Stock</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="stock" id="stock" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
      <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field><br />
    
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Descripción</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="descripcion" id="descripcion" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
      <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field><br />
    
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Costo</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="costo" id="costo" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
        <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field><br />

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Precio venta</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="preciovta" id="preciovta" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
      <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field><br />

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>IGV</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="igv" id="igv" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
        <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field><br />

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>ICB PER</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="icbper" id="icbper" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
        <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field><br />
     
      
    </form>
  </mat-card-content>
```

Formulario para editar los datos del producto. Como se observa puedo cargar todos los valores; solo para el caso de la marca que no logro como fijar el valor al mat-select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden orientar como cargar un atributo cuando su tipo es de una clase determinada a un mat select

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="marcaSeleccionada" placeholder="Mode">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let mar of marca" [value]="mar">
      {{mar.nombre}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

y en tu componente solamente agregas `marcaSeleccionada: 'nombre de la marca'` o si es de un arreglo `marcaSeleccionada = this.marca[0].nombre`, si no funciona con `[(value)]` también puedes intentar con `[(ngModel)]` o bien podrías usar:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="..." [value]="mar" [selected]="i === 0">
```

Comment: Al editar intento cargar la marca que tiene asignada el producto en la base de datos y que se muestre en el select por defecto

Comment: Oh, ya lo edito entonces.

Comment: Pero lo que tienes es un input, entonces donde no coincida habrá problemas. Creo que tus solución sería un `mat-optgroup` donde podrías tener todo organizado por marcas y dentro de cada marca sus artículos correspondientes.
[Select with option groups](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-optgroup)